# C# GDI+ clip draw and more

Tags: c#, zooming, gdi+, clip, pan

I am writing an application that has a panel in which I display:

- Picture background
- Lots of drawn objects (using GDI+ lines, paths,    etc)
- Said objects have some hit detection in mouse move event.

The panel pans and zooms. The panel is double buffered.

So everything is working pretty well - things look good, no flicker, but I am at the point where I am trying to focus on performance. I take less than 1 ms to draw my objects (per object) BUT when zoomed out I can have upwards of 500 objects to draw, which starts to make everything from the drawing to the hit detection sluggish.

I have already done a few things to try to improve performance like making a list of only the on screen (drawable) objects - but as previously mentioned, when zoomed out, it can still be LOTS. I got the grand idea that maybe instead of updating EVERY object EVERY time, I could implement a simple Invalidate() which would tell the object its made a visual change worthy of drawing. In the object paint code (which is passed e.graphics), I attempted to set the clipping region to the size of the object and only update that portion of the panel BG (also when done, I reset the e.Grpahics.clip). The result was only the invalidated object paints - everything else is blank.

I am confident this is the C#/GDI noob coming out in me and you all will tell me what stupid mistake I've probably overlooked.

At the time of writing this, I realize that I can save *some* time by make the path of my object constant instead of making it fresh every time in the draw function (since all objects paths are identical). I'll update with time I shave off shortly.

Here is the code that paints the BG image (and determines which OBJS to paint) and the OBJ paint code.

```
private void PaintImage(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int scale = 10;  //TARGET ICON BASE SCALE....
            var watch2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            if (bitmap != null && redrawBG)
            {



                float widthZoomed = TgtPanel.Width / Zoom;
                float heigthZoomed = TgtPanel.Height / Zoom;
                //Do checks the reason 30,000 is used is because 
                //much over this will cause DrawImage to crash
                if (widthZoomed > 30000.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = TgtPanel.Width / 30000.0f;
                    widthZoomed = 30000.0f;
                }
                if (heigthZoomed > 30000.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = TgtPanel.Height / 30000.0f;
                    heigthZoomed = 30000.0f;
                }
                //we stop at 2 because at this point you have almost zoomed into a single pixel
                if (widthZoomed < 2.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = TgtPanel.Width / 2.0f;
                    widthZoomed = 2.0f;
                }
                if (heigthZoomed < 2.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = TgtPanel.Height / 2.0f;
                    heigthZoomed = 2.0f;
                }
                float wz2 = widthZoomed / 2.0f;
                float hz2 = heigthZoomed / 2.0f;
                Rectangle drawRect = new Rectangle(
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.X - wz2),
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.Y - hz2),
                    (int)(widthZoomed),
                    (int)(heigthZoomed));


                e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White); //Clear the Back buffer
                //Draw the image, Write image to back buffer, and [render back buffer - no longer using my own backbuffer]
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap,
                         this.TgtPanel.DisplayRectangle, drawRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                //                e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(Zoom, Zoom);
                //              e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap,
                //                    0,0);


                if (draging)
                {  //line to visualize the drag
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Yellow, 10), StartDrag.X, StartDrag.Y, lastMouse.X, lastMouse.Y);
                }

                //this checks for offscreen - works
                if (drawRect.X > iconbitmap.Width || drawRect.X < -(drawRect.Width) ||
                    drawRect.Y > 0 + iconbitmap.Height || drawRect.Y < -(drawRect.Height))
                {
                    label1.Text = "OFF";
                }



            } //if bitmap != null & redraw
                // Font and Brush for the text graphics
                Point mypoint = WorldToScreen(0.75f * scale, 7.0f * scale);
                RectangleF bgrect = new RectangleF();
                bgrect.X = mypoint.X;
                bgrect.Y = mypoint.Y;
                bgrect.Width = (3.5f * scale * Zoom);
                bgrect.Height = (2.0f * scale * Zoom);

                int aFontSizeDefault = 40;
                int aFontSizeMinimum = 2;
                String adrawString = "AAA"; //test this length
                Font aDefaultFont = new Font("MS Sans Serif", aFontSizeDefault, FontStyle.Regular);
                FontAdjustment afa = new FontAdjustment();
                Font AAdjustedFont = afa.GetAdjustedFont(e.Graphics, adrawString,
                aDefaultFont, Convert.ToInt32(bgrect.Width), aFontSizeDefault, aFontSizeMinimum, true);

                //DRAW TGT BG
                var Point1 = ScreenToWorld(0, 0);
                var Point2 = ScreenToWorld(TgtPanel.Width, TgtPanel.Height);
                //getVisible Screen == on;y draw visible targets

                if (redrawBG)
                {
                    VISIBLETARGETS.Clear(); //erase visible tgts array - we're going to update it
                    foreach (Target TGT in THETARGETS)
                        if (TGT.PosX >= Point1.X - 40 && TGT.PosX <= Point2.X - 9) 
                        if (TGT.PosY >= Point1.Y - 83 && TGT.PosY <= Point2.Y - 5)
                        {
                            TGT.OnScreen = true;
                            //drawTarget(TGT, AAdjustedFont, e);
                            VISIBLETARGETS.Add(TGT); //update as visible
                        }
                        else TGT.OnScreen = false;

                    //redrawBG = false;
                }

            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            foreach(Target TGT in VISIBLETARGETS)
            {
                if(TGT.Invalidated || redrawBG) //  THIS IS DRAWING ONLY TGT -- NOT OTHERS, OR BG - FIX THIS WITH CLIPPING? 
                    drawTarget(TGT, AAdjustedFont, e);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            watch2.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;//ElapsedTicks;
            label6.Text = "TotalDrawTime = " + watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            label4.Text = "AvgDrawTime = " + elapsedMs.ToString();
            label5.Text = "VisibleTgts = " + VISIBLETARGETS.Count.ToString();

                AAdjustedFont.Dispose();
                aDefaultFont.Dispose();

                //------------- DRAWING TGT WITH GDI - WITH ORIGINAL BACKBUFFER
              ///  myBuffer.Render(this.TgtPanel.CreateGraphics());

                redrawBG = false;

        }



        public void drawTarget(Target Tgt, Font AAdjustedFont, PaintEventArgs e)
        { 
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            const float scale = 10; //10 is at 1 zoom
            var bgrect = new RectangleF();

            Point mypoint = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 0.75f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 1.0f * scale);
            bgrect.X = mypoint.X;
            bgrect.Y = mypoint.Y;
            bgrect.Width = 3.5f * scale * Zoom;
            bgrect.Height = 7.5f * scale * Zoom;


            //PLAY WITH CLIP
            e.Graphics.Clip = new Region(bgrect);

            //var hbrush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.DarkDownwardDiagonal, Color.White);
            var hbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

            //if(WantToDrawIconBG() ....
            //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hbrush, bgrect);  //ICON BACKGROUND

            //ADDR RECT
           // mypoint = WorldToScreen(0, Tgt.PosY + 7.0f * scale);
            mypoint = WorldToScreen(0, Tgt.PosY + 6.90f * scale); //moved Y up a bit from above
            bgrect.Y = mypoint.Y;
            bgrect.Height = 1.5f * scale * Zoom;
            /////brush.Color = (Color.GhostWhite);
             e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hbrush, bgrect);
             hbrush.Dispose();

            string adrawString = Tgt.Address;
            System.Drawing.Font adrawFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16);
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush adrawBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            System.Drawing.StringFormat adrawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat();
            adrawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(adrawString, AAdjustedFont, adrawBrush, bgrect, adrawFormat); //draw addr
            //======= LETS MAKE THE TGT ICON SHAPE =======

            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate);

            //TARGET POINTS      (w = 3, h = 6) 
            var h1 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 2 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 1.1f * scale);
            var h2 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 3 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 1.1f * scale);
            var n1 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 2 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 2 * scale);
            var n2 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 3 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 2 * scale);
            var s1 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 3 * scale);
            var s2 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 4 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 3 * scale);
            var b1 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 7 * scale);
            var b2 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 4 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 7 * scale);
            var controln2 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1 * scale, (Convert.ToInt32(Tgt.PosY + 0.5 * scale)));
            var controls2 = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 1 * scale);


            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));
            PointF[] npoints = { n2, s2, b2 };
            PointF[] npoints2 = { n1, s1, b1 };
            e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, npoints, 0.5f);
            path.AddCurve(npoints, 0.5f); /////
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, b2, b1);
            path.AddLine(b2, b1); /////
            e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, npoints2, 0.5f);
            path.AddCurve(npoints2, 0.5f); /////

            PointF[] hpoints = { n1, h1, h2, n2 };
            e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, hpoints, 0.1f);
            path.AddCurve(hpoints, 0.1f); /////

            path.CloseAllFigures();
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            if (Zoom > 0.9)  //only draw stroke if big enough to see (and there arent a million targets to draw
            {
                pen.Color = Tgt.Selected ? Color.Chartreuse : Color.FromName(comboBox1.Text); //black default
                pen.Width = Tgt.Selected ? 2 * Zoom : 1 * Zoom;  //draw thicker border if selected

                e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);   ///------------------------------------------STROKE PATH.....
                //e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Color.ForestGreen), path);
            }

         // how much time is wasted making 2 gradient brushes? One we wont even use.
                LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(
                  WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 0 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 5 * scale),
                  WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 5.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 5 * scale),
                Color.ForestGreen,   // Opaque red
                Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));  // Opaque blue

                LinearGradientBrush linRedBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(
                  WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 0 * scale, Tgt.PosY + 5 * scale),
                 WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 5.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 5 * scale),
                Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0),   // Opaque red
                Color.Firebrick);  // Opaque blue


            //FILL TARGET ICON WITH COLOR - UP or DOWN
            if (Tgt.IsUp) e.Graphics.FillPath(linGrBrush, path);
             else e.Graphics.FillPath(linRedBrush, path);
            //------------

            //tgt lines  (cosmetic only)
            if (Zoom > 0.9)  //only draw if big enough to see (and there arent a million targets to draw
            {
                var transPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(150, 200, 200, 200));
                var l1a = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 2.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 1.5f * scale);
                var l1b = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 2.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 6 * scale);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(transPen, l1a, l1b);
                var l2a = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 2.5f * scale);
                var l2b = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 6.5f * scale);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(transPen, l2a, l2b);
                var l3a = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 3.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 2.5f * scale);
                var l3b = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 3.5f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 6.5f * scale);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(transPen, l3a, l3b);
            }

            //Draw Hits....
            mypoint = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1.0f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 3.0f * scale);
            bgrect.X = mypoint.X;
            bgrect.Y = mypoint.Y;
            bgrect.Width = 3.0f * scale * Zoom;
            bgrect.Height = 1.5f * scale * Zoom;
            adrawString = Tgt.Hits.ToString();

            adrawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            if (Zoom > 0.9)  //only draw if big enough to see (and there arent a million targets to draw
            {
                adrawBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100, 100);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(adrawBrush, bgrect);
            }
            adrawBrush.Color = Color.White; 
            e.Graphics.DrawString(adrawString, AAdjustedFont, adrawBrush, bgrect, adrawFormat); //draw hits


            //Draw Score....
            mypoint = WorldToScreen(Tgt.PosX + 1.0f * scale, Tgt.PosY + 5.0f * scale);
            bgrect.X = mypoint.X;
            bgrect.Y = mypoint.Y;
            bgrect.Width = 3.0f * scale * Zoom;
            bgrect.Height = 1.5f * scale * Zoom;
            adrawString = Tgt.Score.ToString();

            adrawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            if (Zoom > 0.9)  //only draw if big enough to see (and there arent a million targets to draw
            {
                adrawBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100, 100);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(adrawBrush, bgrect);
            }
            adrawBrush.Color = Color.White;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(adrawString, AAdjustedFont, adrawBrush, bgrect, adrawFormat); //draw hits



            adrawFont.Dispose();
            adrawBrush.Dispose();
            adrawFormat.Dispose();
            path.Dispose();

            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedTicks;
            //14279 original ticks
            //12764 removing label and reducing font size calcs...
            // 1695 !  removed font size to external calc so it happens only once

            e.Graphics.ResetClip();
            e.Graphics.Clip.Dispose();
            Tgt.Invalidated = false; //dont draw again until change
        }
```

Comment: First of all **do not recreate GDI+ resources on each paint operation**. Pens, brushes, fonts and so on are limited creation-expensive resources. They must be created once and reused whenever it's possible. Moreover they're also wrappers for native resources then they  MUST be properly disposed (they implement IDisposable). This will give you a big big performance boost but there is still a **lot to do there** (too much for a SO question, maybe on CodeReview?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've since removed all the created fonts, brushes, and pens from the paint. This has shaved off more time. I know that I can shave a <technical term>**butt load**</technical term> of time if I store the path outside of the object paint function BUT, I am a curious as to the proper way to do this. Since the path points are based on both the objects X.Y and world scale, what is the best way to approach it. Would I be looking at a fixed path that is somehow transformed using the transform matrix and worldTOscreen equations? Thanks.

Comment: FYI: Original 500 Object Draw Time 500ms, After removing fonts/pens/brushes from paint func: 338ms, After removing gradient fill and cosmetic lines: 269ms. After removing outline stroke: 140ms. Quick, but not nearly as pretty.

Comment: You can scale graphics object using transformations.

Comment: You don't need to *remove* brushes, just create it outside paint or use predefined ones. Gradient is *bad beast* because need actual rect but you can use solid fill doing dragging and repaint with gradient when *static*. Drawing itself is very very fast, resource creation is many many times slower. You can even rebuild path each time but ideally everything that can be done outside paint...must be done outside. Here. NET and *unmanaged* Win32 worlds coincide

Comment: Do all those item change all the time or can you cache some in a Bitmap? If you use a PictureBox you could use its extra image level to display the cached parts.. (You could do that in a Panel as well, I guess.)

Comment: Adriano-I misspoke, I have only moved the brush/pen creation outside of the proc.  TaW-Items represent real world devices. They change at max every 300ms but realistically, it will be several seconds if not minutes between updates. I have made concessions for marking individual items for drawing, but I had an issue where, in that case, ONLY the marked item would draw (and the bg and other unchanged items were blank). Now that you mention caching a bitmap, I can try to copy current panel canvas to bitmap - bitblt the bitmap back to canvas, then use a cliprect and update on the required section.